# How to write an HTTP response to stdout?

Tags: go

I am trying to write to stdout the raw HTTP response received from a GET request.  I thought `httputil.DumpResponse` would do what I want but it seems to include mysterious byte counts on "bigger" responses.

For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 16 Oct 2017 15:07:53 GMT

1f43
THE ACTUAL BODY CONTENT WHICH IS 8003 BYTES
0
```

The `1f43` seems to be the length of the response body.  Go's `http.response` talks about trailers, so maybe the `0` is the size of the trailer.

My code is:

```
    var resp *http.Response
    var err error

    if *isPost {
        resp, err = http.Post(url, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", strings.NewReader(*data))
    } else {
        resp, err = http.Get(url)
    }

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    dump, err := httputil.DumpResponse(resp, true)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s", dump)
```

I have read the code for `DumpResponse` and `TransferWriter` but I can't figure out where the `1f43` and `0` come from.

If I make the same request with curl, I don't get the `1f43` and `0` in the response.

Is this the best way to write the raw HTTP response?  If so, how can I fix it to avoid these byte counts?

Comment: This "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" is the reason. Chunked responses actually _do_ (in fact must) have these "1f43" lengths. So: do not make chunked responses e.g. by setting the Content-Length (see https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Write).

Comment: Aha, ok.  With that info, I found where this happens: in the `Write()` function of `net/http/internal/chunked` [here](https://golang.org/src/net/http/internal/chunked.go).

Comment: I'm not generating the responses; I'm sending requests and trying to print the dechunked response I get back.

Comment: Well, then keep it chunked because that _is_ the response. Or read the whole body, replace Transfer-Encoding with Content-Length and resupply the body before DumpRespons'ing.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you.  If you want to make that an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use interfaces for that,

The http.Get call returns a pointer to a Response type, which contains a Body, if you check Body interfaces, you can see that the Body implements the io.ReadCloser, which, implements both the Reader and Closer interfaces;

By understanding these interfaces you  can make use of eg: io.Copy

```
func Copy(dst Writer, src Reader) (written int64, err error) {...}
```

As second argument, you could pass the Response Body, which implements the Reader.

As first argument, Writer, you could both implement your own custom type, and create a func to implement the Writer interface, or, you can also use the built in os.Stdout, which already implements it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    resp, err := http.Get("http://google.com")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    io.Copy(os.Stdout, resp.Body)
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I just realised I never actually stated that I wanted the response's headers too (which was why I was using `dumpResponse()`) – but your answer answers the question I asked.

Comment: I couldn't see a built-in method to write the headers so I write them out myself, e.g. `fmt.Print(resp.Proto + " " + resp.Status + "\r\n")`.